# Rust nested fors itering over the same vector

Tags: rust

I was trying to change some of vector elements, while itering over the vector.

```
for operator in operators {
    // add left side
    let node = nodes[operator.index-1].clone();
    nodes[operator.index].children.push(node);

    // add right side
    let node = nodes[operator.index+1].clone();
    nodes[operator.index].children.push(node);

    // remove used nodes
    nodes.remove(operator.index+1);
    nodes.remove(operator.index-1);

    // two items were removed, so every index higher than the current one needs to be lowered by 2
    for operator2 in &mut operators {
        if operator2.index > operator.index {
            operator2.index -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly this isn't possible in rust, because error says that 'operators' was moved. I tried to change for to look like this:
`for operator in &operators`, but then it has problem getting 'operators' as mutable and immutable at the same time. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use simple loops with indices:

```rust
for operator_idx in 0..operators.len() {
    let operator = &operators[operator_idx];

    // add left side
    let node = nodes[operator.index-1].clone();
    nodes[operator.index].children.push(node);

    // add right side
    let node = nodes[operator.index+1].clone();
    nodes[operator.index].children.push(node);

    // remove used nodes
    nodes.remove(operator.index+1);
    nodes.remove(operator.index-1);

    // two items were removed, so every index higher than the current one needs to be lowered by 2
    for operator2 in &mut operators {
        if operator2.index > operator.index {
            operator2.index -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost worked, only needed to put everything before for loop inside brackets, so the operator reference is closed when second loop starts.

Comment: @GoatPonny Hmm... Interesting, NLL should already allow that. Can you share a link to a playground?

Comment: I don't know how to give link to a playground, but I think it is because I used `operator.index` inside second loop. When I inserted brackets and  cloned operator.index into other variable problem disappeared. I thought putting brackets solved the problem, but actually cloning the variable did and brackets were obsolete.